# Cross browser test

Tags: testing, browser, authentication

I have to do login to an application with two different browsers (IE & FF) and hence I tried to do cross browser test. When the URL gets passed to IE, I am getting link as **"Continue to this website not recommended"**, whereas the same link will not be displayed in FF. In the below if I use this statement `driver.findElement(By.id("overridelink")).click();` then it works fine in IE but failing in firefox since there wont be any link in FF.

please let me know the possible where one script should run in both the browsers. Below is the script which am trying

```
@Test 
@Parameters("browser")
public void verifypagetitle(String browsername) { 

   if(browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("IE"))
   {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                "D:\\2.53.1\\IEDriverServer.exe");
       driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

   }

   else if (browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) 
   {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin",
                "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
       driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   }
     driver.get("URL");
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     driver.findElement(By.id("overridelink")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("userid");
     driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys("pwd");
     driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the IE security level. In my experience if I change it to Low, the warning is not present. You can try and see if this will solve the issue in your case.

[image]

Another solution is to add conditional logic to [check the browser](http://mashtips.com/get-system-os-browser-version-java-selenium-webdriver/) being used. Something like this:

```
Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) browserDriver).getCapabilities();
String browsername = cap.getBrowserName();
// This block to find out if it is IE
if ("internet explorer".equalsIgnoreCase(browsername)) {
  driver.findElement(By.id("overridelink")).click();
}
```

Comment: I tried this it didn't work for me. Is there any way that I can skip this particular line  "driver.findElement(By.id("overridelink")).click(); "  in FF .